# Munin: Change plugin category using munin.conf, when plugin filename contains dots?

Tags: plugins, configuration, categories, munin

Each plugin in munin has some configuration settings and one of them is the category it belongs to (graph_category).

I would like to change the category of some plugins to the non-default one. As I see in the munin.conf man page, I can change specific directives for plugins per host like this:

```
[machine1.your.dom]
    address localhost
    load.graph_title Edited title of the load-graph
```

Now I tried the same with the ping plugin and the graph_category instead of the graph_title as shows this example, but I can't get it to work.

I have a machine pinging different hosts with different meaning, so I would like to group them in different categories for easy access.

for example:

```
ping_192.168.1.1    <- category: lan connectivity
ping_192.168.1.2    <- category: lan connectivity
ping_10.0.0.10      <- category: intranet connectivity
ping_10.0.0.20      <- category: intranet connectivity
ping_www.google.com <- category: internet connectivity
```

UPDATE:
I tried the same with another plugin and it worked. I suspect it's something with the periods included in the domain or IP address of the ping plugin name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution after reading the following ticket:

http://munin-monitoring.org/ticket/526

When a plugin name contain dots, these dots must be replaced with an underscore.
So the solution to the example in my question will work like this:

```
[machine1.your.dom]
    address localhost
    ping_192_168_1_1.graph_category lan connectivity
    ping_192_168_1_2.graph_category lan connectivity
    ping_10_0_0_10.graph_category intranet connectivity
    ping_10_0_0_20.graph_category intranet connectivity
    ping_www_google_com.graph_category internet connectivity
```